# how to map model class to infrastructure using the clean architecture

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, clean-architecture

I have confusion about clean architecture, in my project i have two projects one is Infrastructure where i create database and model entities,i have Core project where i created my interfaces and my models,the interfaces inside core are implemnted inside the infrastructure,for example in my Core project i have IDataHandler class,i put i all the signiture which interact with DB,and i implement those signitures inside DataHandler which is in Infrastructure project..now here is my question,
in my Core IDataHandler looks:

```
public  interface IDataHandler
{
    public  Task<StudentsModel> GetStudent(string id);
}
```

in my Infrastructure i have StudensEntity which is the exact copy of the StudentModel,but when i want to implemet the IDataHandler i cant use like this:

```
public  interface DataHandler:IDataHanlder
{
    public  Task<StudentsEntity> GetStudent(string id);
}
```

it the return type is not the same as its interface,even thought they have the same properties,i ope you understand what im trying ask,if so,what should i do?

Comment: Unfortunately this is not a good fit for stackoverflow, its about an architectural pattern which can have many solutions, open to interpretation, and can have no right or wrong answers. Maybe try, SoftwareEngineering.

Comment: @TheGeneral i read onion pattern and came up with this.

Comment: Why is your Datahandler not directly creating and returning the model class? Why do you have additional entity class?

Answer (score 0):

The solution you came up with reflects clean architecture principles, especially in regard to the separation between repository interfaces (`IDataHandler`) and repository implementations (`DataHandler`) and between what you refer to as "models" (`StudentModel`) and "model entities" (`StudentEntity`).

> in my Infrastructure i have StudensEntity which is the exact copy of the StudentModel

In order to make this work, the core model should actually be either an abstract class or an interface, e.g. interface `IStudent` instead of class `StudentModel`, and infrastructure model `StudentEntity` should implement that interface. This may lead to such (simplified) code:

```
// Core (domain language)
public interface IStudent
{
    long Id { get; }
    string Name { get; }
}

// Infrastructure
public StudentEntity : IStudent
{
    public StudentEntity(long id, string name)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.Name = name;
    }

    public long Id { get; }
    public string Name { get; }
}

// Core (domain language)
public interface IDataHandler
{
    Task<IStudent> GetStudent(string id);
}

// Infrastructure
public class DataHandler : IDataHanlder
{
    public async Task<IStudent> GetStudent(string id)
    {
        // Construct StudentEntity from database and return it.
    }
}
```